# How to auto indent the elixir code in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, elixir

I have installed Sublime Text 3 and the Elixir package. However, when I try to Line -> Reindent the Elixir code, it does not indent properly. How can I indent Elixir code properly in Sublime text?

The code snippet:

```
defmodule Drop do

def drop do
setup
handle_drops
end

def handle_drops do
receive do
{from, planemo, distance} ->
send(from, {planemo, distance, fall_velocity(planemo, distance)})
handle_drops
end
end

def fall_velocity(planemo, distance) when distance >= 0 do
{:atomic, [p | _]} = :mnesia.transaction(fn() ->
:mnesia.read(Planemo, planemo) end)
:math.sqrt(2 * p.gravity * distance)
end

def setup do
:mnesia.create_schema([node()])
:mnesia.start()
:mnesia.create_table(PlanemoTable, [{:attributes,
[:name, :gravity, :diameter, :distance_from_sun]},
{:record_name, :planemo}])
f = fn ->
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :mercury, gravity: 3.7,
diameter: 4878, distance_from_sun: 57.9), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :venus, gravity: 8.9,
diameter: 12104, distance_from_sun: 108.2), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :earth, gravity: 9.8,
diameter: 12756, distance_from_sun: 149.6), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :moon, gravity: 1.6,
diameter: 3475, distance_from_sun: 149.6), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :mars, gravity: 3.7,
diameter: 6787, distance_from_sun: 227.9), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :ceres, gravity: 0.27,
diameter: 950, distance_from_sun: 413.7), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :jupiter, gravity: 23.1,
diameter: 142796, distance_from_sun: 778.3), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :saturn, gravity: 9.0,
diameter: 120660, distance_from_sun: 1427.0), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :uranus, gravity: 8.7,
diameter: 51118, distance_from_sun: 2871.0), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :neptune, gravity: 11.0,
diameter: 30200, distance_from_sun: 4497.1), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :pluto, gravity: 0.6,
diameter: 2300, distance_from_sun: 5913.0), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :haumea, gravity: 0.44,
diameter: 1150, distance_from_sun: 6484.0), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :makemake, gravity: 0.5,
diameter: 1500, distance_from_sun: 6850.0), :write)
:mnesia.write(PlanemoTable, Planemo.planemo(name: :eris, gravity: 0.8,
diameter: 2400, distance_from_sun: 10210.0), :write)
end

:mnesia.transaction(f)
end
end
```

Comment: So, the code did not change at all when you tried to indent it? Can you please add the snippet that you were trying to indent to your question?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Can I post the code in comment?

Comment: Please edit your question instead and format it as source code. Code in comments is often hard to read, especially when you're dealing with whitespace related problems such as indentation.

Comment: In addition to Patrick's wise suggestion, you may want to try different constructs to see if this problem is related to some specific code.  For example if you do a simple `defmodule T do`/`end` with one simple empty function inside, do you have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Failure to reindent correctly is often a sign of there being a syntax error in your code.  Check to make sure that you haven't forgotted a `def` or `end` or a matching bracket or quotation marks...